# Let $y=(x-p)^2+(x-q)^2$ where $p$ and $q$ are constants. For what value of $x$ is $y$ a minimum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, quadratics

> Let $y=(x-p)^2+(x-q)^2$ where $p$ and $q$ are constants. For what value of $x$ is $y$ a minimum?

Using logic, I obtained the correct answer, $\dfrac{p-q}2$, but how can I solve it using equations?

Comment: If the question is `For what value of x` then `(p-q)/2` is not the right answer. For one thing, $y$ is symmetric in $p,q$ thus so needs be the $x$ which minimizes $y$. For the right $x$, see the posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$y=2x^2-2(p+q)x+p^2+q^2=\dfrac{\{2x-(p+q)\}^2+2(p^2+q^2)-(p+q)^2}2$$

Now for real $2x-p-q,$  $$\{2x-(p+q)\}^2\ge0$$

Alternatively, $$2x^2-2(p+q)x+p^2+q^2-y=0$$ which is a Quadratic Equation in $x$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant $=?$ must be $\ge0$

Comment: Can I use $-\dfrac b{2a}$

Comment: @suomynonA,  I think you are referring  $$ax^2+bx+c=a\left(x+\dfrac b {2a}\right)^2+\dfrac{4ca-b^2}{4a}$$ which is right

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be stated geometrically (and more generally) as:

> Given two fixed points $ P,Q\,$, then $XP^2+XQ^2$ is minimized when $X$ is the midpoint $O$ of $PQ$.

The above follows from the triangle [median length formula](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/LengthOfMedian.shtml) $XO^2 = \frac{1}{2}(XP^2+XQ^2)-\frac{1}{4}PQ^2$ $\iff$ $XP^2+XQ^2 = 2 XO^2 + \frac{1}{2}PQ^2 \ge \frac{1}{2}PQ^2$ with equality iff $X \equiv O$.

For collinear points of abscissae $p,q,x,o=(p+q)/2$ this reduces to the posted question.

Answer (score 1):

Since $y(p)=y(q)$ the first coordinate of the vertex is $(p+q)/2$.